# Strange shared folder issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, shared-folders, azure-activedirectory, synology-diskstation

Same laptop. When I log in, a shared folder on our network is accessible. But when another user logs in, the same shared folder is not accessible. The shared folder is public. The laptop has Windows 10 on it and we log in using Azure AD accounts.

Comment: What are the NTFS and share permissions for this folder exactly?

Comment: Ask your admins.